# plotting the top 5 values from a table in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm very new to R so this may be a simple question. I have a table of data that contains frequency counts of species like this:

```
  Acidobacteria              47
  Actinobacteria            497
  Apicomplexa                 7
  Aquificae                  16
  Arthropoda                 26
  Ascomycota                101
  Bacillariophyta             1
  Bacteroidetes           50279
  ...
```

There are about 50 species in the table. As you can see some of the values are a lot larger than the others. I would like to have a stacked barplot with the top 5 species by percentage and one category of 'other' that has the sum of all the other percentages. So my barplot would have 6 categories total (top 5 and other).

I have 3 additional datasets (sample sites) that I would like to do the same thing to only highlighting the first dataset's top 5 in each of these datasets and put them all on the same graph. The final graph would have 4 stacked bars showing how the top species in the first dataset change in each additional dataset.

I made a sample plot by hand (tabulated the data outside of R and just fed in the final table of percentages) to give you an idea of what I'm looking for: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1938620/phylumSum2.jpg

I would like to put these steps into an R script so I can create these plots for many datasets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say your data is in the data.frame `DF`

```
DF <- read.table(textConnection(
"Acidobacteria              47
Actinobacteria            497
Apicomplexa                 7
Aquificae                  16
Arthropoda                 26
Ascomycota                101
Bacillariophyta             1
Bacteroidetes           50279"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(DF) <- c("Species","Count")
```

Then you can determine which species are in the top 5 by

```
top5Species <- DF[rev(order(DF$Count)),"Species"][1:5]
```

Each of the data sets can then be converted to these 5 and "Other" by

```
DF$Group <- ifelse(DF$Species %in% top5Species, DF$Species, "Other")
DF$Group <- factor(DF$Group, levels=c(top5Species, "Other"))
DF.summary <- ddply(DF, .(Group), summarise, total=sum(Count))
DF.summary$prop <- DF.summary$total / sum(DF.summary$total)
```

Making `Group` a factor keeps them all in the same order in `DF.summary` (largest to smallest per the first data set).

Then you just put them together and plot them as you did in your example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried to make a list of the top 5 species as you suggested but got the error:
Error in DF$Count : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I should mention the species are already in a table created with the table() function.

Comment: I don't know what format your data is in; I had to make up a data set that looked like your data, but it very well might have a different structure.  You would need to post the data.frame you have (or whatever format it is in) so that the example is reproducible.

Comment: Writing the table out to a file and re-reading it seems to have worked. DF.summary gives me the table I want, thank you! Now I just have to go through the commands and figure out what they're doing :p

Answer (score 1):

## We should make it a habit to use data.table wherever possible:

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(DF,key="Count")
DT[order(-rank(Count), Species)[6:nrow(DT)],Species:="Other"]
DT<-DT[, list(Count=sum(Count),Pcnt=sum(Count)/DT[,sum(Count)]),by="Species"]
```